# How to conditionally skip number of iteration steps in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

We have a list `item_list`,

```
item_list = ["a", "b", "XYZ", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

We iterate over its items with a for loop, if item is `"XYZ"`, skip items `"c", "d", "e"` and continue with `"f"`:

```
for item in item_list:
    if item == "XYZ":
       do_something()
       skip_3_items() ----> skip items "c", "d", "e"
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

What could be the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to skip those particular items or any next three items in the list ?

Comment: You could use a counter and `continue` until it's 0, but i'm pretty sure the most pythonic way would be rethinking your loop entirely

Comment: @jramirez I want to skip next 3 items in the list

Comment: Then kindall's answer will do that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list_iter = iter(item_list)

for item in list_iter:
    if item == "XYZ":
        do_something()
        for _ in range(3):   # skip next 3 items
            next(list_iter, None)

# etc.
```

Basically, rather than iterating over the list directly, you create an abstraction for it called an *iterator* and iterate over that. You can tell the iterator to advance to the next item by calling `next(...)` which we do three times to skip the next three items. The next time through the loop, it picks up at the next item after that.

Comment: What does next(list_iter) do?

Comment: @alwbtc it advances the iterator one position

Comment: You should put those `next` statements in a `try ... except StopIteration`

Comment: @alwbtc if you're new to iterators, you should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/1595865)

Comment: Instead of catching a StopIteration, since you're ignoring the value anyway, you can simply use the default arg, e.g. `next(list_iter, None)`

Comment: What if it is a dictionary, but not a list?

Comment: @DSM has the better idea. also changed it to a loop rather than writing `next()` three times.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has mentioned a while loop, I will:

```
item_list = ["a", "b", "XYZ", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
i = 0
while i < len(item_list):
    item = item_list[i]
    if item == "XYZ":
        do_something()
        i += 3
    else:
        do_something_else()
    i += 1
```

Comment: I believe no one has mentioned because it is usually very "non-pythonic" to use while. The whole point of using iterators is to get away from counting integers and stuff. Your code works, of course

Answer (score 1):

Use an iterator:

```
$ cat t.py 
item_list = ["a", "b", "XYZ", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

it = iter(item_list)
for item in it:
    if item == "XYZ":
       print item
       for _ in range(3):
           next(it, None)
    else:
        print item
```

This gives:

```
$ python t.py 
a
b
XYZ
f
g
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split the processing it two parts for sake of readability

```
>>> def foo(item_list,key = "XYZ", skip = 3):
    from itertools import takewhile, islice
    def do_something():
        return "do_something()"
    def do_something_else():
        return "do_something_else()"
    it = iter(item_list)
    for items in takewhile(lambda e: e != key, it):
        print items, do_something_else()
    print do_something()
    it = islice(it,skip, None)
    for items in it:
        print items, do_something_else()


>>> foo(item_list)
a do_something_else()
b do_something_else()
do_something()
f do_something_else()
g do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd store a counter that handles skipping items.

```
def skipper(item_list):
    skip_count = 0
    for item in item_list:
        if item == "XYZ":
            skip_count = 3
        else:
            if skip_count:
                skip_count -= 1
            else:
                # do_something()
                print item,
```

Example:

```
In [23]: item_list
Out[23]: ['a', 'b', 'XYZ', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

In [24]: skipper(item_list)
a b f g
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write it out like this, personally:

```
xyz_i = item_list.index('XYZ')

do_something('XYZ') #or do_something(item_list[xyz_i]) but.. just save yourself the list lookup

for x in item_list[xyz_i+4:]:
    do_something_else(x)
```