# How to make exception for a number in the range of for loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

In Python when I define a range for a variable, for example

```
for i in range(0,9):
```

but here I want to prevent `i` from taking a value of `7`. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to conditionally skip number of iteration steps in a for loop in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169354/how-to-conditionally-skip-number-of-iteration-steps-in-a-for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you want to do. If you just want to create a list you can simply do:

```
ignore=[2,7] #list of indices to be ignored
l = [ind for ind in xrange(9) if ind not in ignore]
```

which yields

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

You can also directly use these created indices in a for loop e.g. like this:

```
[ind**2 for ind in xrange(9) if ind not in ignore]
```

which gives you

```
[0, 1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 64]
```

or you apply a function

```
def someFunc(value):
    return value**3

[someFunc(ind) for ind in xrange(9) if ind not in ignore]
```

which yields

```
[0, 1, 27, 64, 125, 216, 512]
```