# Skipping array values in for loops in python

Tags: python

I am trying to skip a value (or 2 at a time) from an array in a for loop. Please refer to the code below:

```
loop = True
product = ['p3','p5','p7','16GB','32GB','1TB','2TB','19in','23in','Mini Tower', 'Midi Tower', '2 ports','4 ports']
while loop:
  for i in product:
    print('Would you like the following component: ',i,)
    input()
    if input == 'y':
```

If they choose that part, I would like to skip to the next component. Is there any way I can do that in the loop?? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, can you continue your example. It seems like its not fully pasted.

Comment: I was wondering what would come after that last line in order to skip the next value in the array

Comment: Can you add one expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to conditionally skip number of iteration steps in a for loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21169354/2823755)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting a skip flag, then doing nothing for the next iteration if it is True:

```
product = ['p3','p5','p7','16GB','32GB','1TB','2TB','19in','23in','Mini Tower', 'Midi Tower', '2 ports','4 ports']

skip = False
for i in product:
  if skip:
    print("Skipping: " + i)
    skip = False
    continue
  if input('Would you like the following component: ' + i) == 'y':
    print("Selected: ", i)
    skip = True
```

However I'm guessing you are wanting the person to select a processor, memory, screen etc - which is really multiple questions, each with multiple options. In this case, I'd suggest splitting this into a nested list, and stopping after any one selection for each - something like:

```
product = [['p3','p5','p7'], ['16GB','32GB','1TB','2TB'], ['19in','23in'], ['Mini Tower', 'Midi Tower'], ['2 ports','4 ports']]

for part in product:
  for i in part:
    if input('Would you like the following component: '+i) == 'y':
      print("Selected: ", i)
      break
```